# what is the Bs4 way to do the js command "document.getElementsByClasName"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, getelementsbyclassname

Is there a way in bs4 to do a command similar to the JavaScript command

```
document.getElementsByClassName('exampleClassName')
```

In python?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
url = example.com
page = get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html_parser')
soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class': 'exampleClassName'})
```

If not, is there a way to scrape it another way?

Comment: Example from the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class): `soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do something equivalent.

With beautifulsoup, you can use css selectors and select by class:

```
soup.select('.exampleClassName')
```

You can use lxml, and use xpath with a class filter:

```
doc.xpath(//'*[@class="exampleClassName"])
```

or if you really like that particular phrase, you can use [AdvancedHTMLParser](https://github.com/kata198/AdvancedHTMLParser) which actually has a method

> `getElementsByClassName` - Returns a list of all elements containing one or more space-separated class names

It all depends on your style and preferences.